# VSTO 2005 under VS 2010 - possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto

I know that VS 2010 by default supports only Office 2007 and up. However is there any way to install VSTO 2005 into VS 2010? If you have tried this route, I'd appreciate knowing your findings.

Comment: Is the issue that VSTO 2005 is .NET 1.1 assemblies? I've certainly had issues running .NET 1.1 assemblies in 2010.

Comment: No, VSTO 2005 targets MS-Office 2003, that's my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the VSTO 2005 toolkit was a seperate installation, AFAIK. You might not get the project templates showing up in 2010, but I'd think you could still manually reference the older VSTO assemblies.

Have you tried creating the VSTO project in vs2008 and then loading it in 2010?